# How to save multiple rows using jquery ajax in CI

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In my html, rows are added dynamically by pressing a button.

```
<button id="add-row">Add New Row</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row"><!-- Begins with 1 row -->
    <input type="text" class="text"><input type="number" class="number">
  </div>
  <div class="row"><!-- IF user adds 1 row -->
     <input type="text" class="text"><input type="number" class="number">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

In my jQuery

```
//Add row
$('#add-row').on('click',function(){
      $('.container').prepend('<div class="row">'+
                                '<input type="text" class="text"><input type="number" class="number">'+
                              '</div>');
});
//Save
$('#save').on('click',function(){
  var text = $('.text').val();
  var number = $('.number').val();
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: BASE_URL+'save/saverows',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {text:text,number:number},
  async: false,
  success: function(data){ 
      alert('Rows saved!');
      } 
  }); 
});
```

In my CI Controller

```
public function saveRows(){
    $data = array(
        'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
        'number' => $this->input->post('number')
    );

    $this->Row_model->saveAll($data);
}
```

In my CI Model

```
 public function saveAll($data){
    $this->db->insert('savehere', $data);
  }
```

Database table looks like this

```
ID  TEXT  NUMBER
1   a     11
2   b     22
3   c     33
4   d     44
```

What I have is just for saving a single row only. How can I accomplish this if there are more than 1? I have an idea of using loop but I do not know how to implement it here. I've also read about CI's inserting by batch but it has a fixed number of rows to be saved.

My problem is in the `#save onclick`. How to retrieve all the `text` and `number` values and then pass it to `jquery ajax` then to `codeigniter controller`.

Using Ilan Hasanov's answer below. The console.log of the arrays is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++) {
      console.log(arrText[i]+" "+arrNumber[i]);
}
text 100
text2 55
```

Comment: Change `dataType: 'html'` to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: How would `data :{}` look like?

Comment: Its `json` object. Do it and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a function for you that will loop and asign your inputs.

```
$('#add-row').on('click', function() {
$('.container').prepend('<div class="row">' + '<input type="text" class="text"><input type="number" class="number">' + '</div>');
});

//Save
$('#save').on('click', function() {
var arr = [];
  $(".row").each(function(index) {
  var text   = $(this).find('input[type=text]').eq(index).val();
  var number = $(this).find('input[type=number]').eq(index).val();
   arr.push({
      text: text,
      number: number
   });
});

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: BASE_URL+'save/saverows',
      data: {batch:arr},
      async: false,
      success: function(data){
          alert('Rows saved!');
      }
  });
});
```

In you Controller you do

```
public function saveRows(){
$this->db->insert_batch('savehere', $this->input->post('batch'));
}

'savehere' replace to your table name
```

We made the array before in the jQuery in your database structure so it has to be inserted nice and short code.

Depending on your database structure

```
arr.push({
   text: text,
   number: number
});
```

or if in your database uppercase then

```
arr.push({
   TEXT: text,
   NUMBER: number
});
```

Comment: My problem begins in the AJAX in jQuery. How to pass multiple rows with the same columns. In the `data` line of the AJAX.

Comment: @IIan I think he have multiple text and number fields. he want to submit multiple objects. So it might be needed to iterate over `text` and `number` input values

Comment: Yes. My problem is in the `#save onclick`. How to retrieve all the `text` and `number` values and then pass it to `jquery ajax` then to `codeigniter controller`.

Comment: @iamDevlin you need to loop the dynamic inputs see my edit

Comment: I tried it. Nothing is saved. Nothing happens. No error in the console. EDIT: I was using `json` before so I changed it to `html` but still not saved. I get the alert `Rows saved!` though.

Comment: @iamDevlin try to console log arrNumber before ajax what it gives?

Comment: It gives the correct values. I think the problem is in the controller's side.

Comment: @iamDevlin add to your post the output from console please

Comment: I tried to manually add some data in the controller to check if the controller is really called and the data is saved. It seems that the array is not being received properly. Is there anyway to `echo` the values of `$data` in the controller?

Comment: @iamDevlin I have updated my code check it out! has to work.

Comment: It now saves but the data is connected. I'll try to fix it first. 
`Object {text: "ab", number: "5050"}
Object {text: "ab", number: "5050"}`

Comment: Fixed it. I just added `eq(index)`

Answer (score 0):

Take name and ID of every input field, which should be unique
Send the form by serializing to controller

Answer (score 0):

At server end we need to generate array of rows like shown [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
//Save
$('#save').on('click',function(){
    var data = [];
    $('.text').each(function(index){
        // text and number are datatypes in database. so i mentioned respected column name
        var row = { "text_col": $(this).val(), "number_col": $('.number')[index].val()   }; 
   data.push(row);
     });

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: BASE_URL+'save/saverows',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: data,
          async: false,
          success: function(data){
        if(data == "done"){
        alert('Rows saved!');
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function saveRows(){
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
    $data = $this->input->post();
    // I assume row_model already loaded by you.
    $this->Row_model->saveAll($data);
    $this->output->set_output("done");
    }
    $this->output->set_output("failed");
}
```

Inside `Row_model`

```
public function saveAll($data){
    $this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $data);
 }
```

I hope this will helps. I have not tested code. So if you find any problem feel free to edit.

Comment: `$('.text').each(function(index,val)`. Wouldn't this just loop through the `text inputs`? I'm not so familiar with the `index,val` parameters. EDIT: I think I get it. I will give this a try.

Comment: @iamDevlin good catch. updated answer. EDIT: Hope you get solution.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: val.val is not a function`

Comment: Updated answer we need to pass that object again to jQuery